# Mongo/express cannot load route (Unexpected '<' in postman)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, routes

Been trying to get user user object by id from parameters, using User.findById and cannot access this route.

Postman response:

```
Cannot GET /users/get/
```

with status 404 (not found) which is wierd.
Postman JSON response:
Unexpected '<'

Been using express-promise-router but also tried with default express.Router();

Here is my code:

routes/users.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = require('express-promise-router')();
const passport = require('passport');
const router1 = express.Router();
require('../passport');

const { validateBody, schemas } = require('../helpers/routeHelpers');
const UsersController = require('../controllers/users');

const passportSignIn = passport.authenticate('local', { session: false });
const passportJWT = passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false });

router.route('/signup')
  .post(validateBody(schemas.authSchema), UsersController.signUp);


router.route('/signin')
  .post(validateBody(schemas.authSchema), passportSignIn, UsersController.signIn);

router.route('/get/:id')
  .get(UsersController.getUser);


router.route('/secret')
  .get(passportJWT, UsersController.secret);
```

controllers/users

```
module.exports = router;
const JWT = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/user');
const { JWT_SECRET } = require('../configuration');

const signToken = (user) => {
  return JWT.sign({
    iss: 'CodeWorkr',
    sub: user.id,
    iat: new Date().getTime(), // current time
    exp: new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 1) // current time + 1 day ahead
  }, JWT_SECRET);
};

module.exports = {
  signUp: async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.value.body;

    // Check if there is a user with the same email
    const foundUser = await User.findOne({ 'local.email': email });
    if (foundUser) {
      return res.status(403).json({ error: 'Email is already in use' });
    }
    // Create a new user
    const newUser = new User({
      method: 'local',
      local: {
        email: email,
        password: password
      }
    });

    await newUser.save();

    // Generate the token
    const token = signToken(newUser);
    // Respond with token
    return res.status(200).json({ token });
  },
  signIn: async (req, res) => {
    // Generate token
    const token = signToken(req.user);
    res.status(200).json({ token });
  }, 
  getUser: async (req, res) => {
    User.findById(req.params.id)
      .then((user) => {
        res.status(200).json({ user });
        console.log('test');
      });
  },

  secret: async (req, res) => {
    console.log('I managed to get here!');
    res.json({ secret: 'resource' });
  }
};
```

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const db = require('./configuration/config').mongoURI;
const dbTest = require('./configuration/config').mongoURITest;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  mongoose.connect(dbTest, { useMongoClient: true });
} else {
  mongoose.connect(db, { useMongoClient: true });
}

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
// Middlewares moved morgan into if for clear tests
if (!process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
}
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Routes
app.use('/users', require('./routes/users'));

// Start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port);
console.log(`Server listening at ${port}`);
```

Other post routes works fine,

Comment: Are you trying to load `/users/get/` (without id)? Because you indeed do not have a route for that.

Comment: I just fixed... in postman i requested like that get/:3243241231 (where numbers is user id) and i did forgot to delete colon. Now its working